# jQuery & IE7 render bug with slideToggle()

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, slidetoggle

I have worked quite a bit with jQuery and slidetoggle effects without coming across this bug before. The page is http://gilman.oomphdev.com, and the bug is when a user clicks the "What's This?" tag at the top of the page in IE7. Also, when one clicks the "Contribute Yours" link (right hand column, bottom-ish of white box) to open the comment form.

The slideToggle effect is pushing some content down, but not others, and the element being turned from display: none to display:block flickers and then disappears. There are elements with "float" inside the container being shown/hidden, but I use a clearfix to help give the container height.

I thought this was a z-index issue, so I found some jQuery that looped through the whole DOM and manually gave every DIV a z-index, but that did not help. I also played with position:relative on some elements but that didn't help either. I was using CSS3 PIE to render some CSS3 effects, but have since turned that off in order to narrow down the field of possible bugs.

So far, I'm stumped. Any insight would be appreciated. My main stylesheet is at:

/wp-content/themes/thinking/styles/screen.css

I also have a stylesheet in that directory for ie.css and reset.css

Comment: Your link is redirecting me to a WP-login. Can you give us a correct link?

Comment: Right... that's the development server. Well, the site has been soft-launched, so, yeah... here is the public URL: http://thinkingarizona.com

Comment: After playing with it some more (and leaving it for a day so I could think more clearly) I figured out that the problem is with hasLayout. The clear was fixed to be block in ie7. I applied the style position: absolute to the body class .ie7 (a hasLayout trigger), and now jQuery slideToggle pushes the proper elements down nicely. Setting position: relative on the wrappers or the #id containers didn't help, nor giving individual elements hasLayout. Setting all elements to have "position" until that position is redefined seemed to do the trick. Thanks to those who helped me work through it.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem with jquery slideToggle()